# Wait for compositor to finish before saving image to file - Python Scripting

Tags: python, scripting, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to write a script that will tweak some settings in the compositor, then save the resulting image.

However, **The resulting image is NOT receiving the changes that are being made in the compositor.** I suspect that blender is not, "waiting for the compositor to finish" before saving the image.

I've tried using Application handlers, but I don't really understand how to use them in this case.

Any help? Here's the code in question, without attempting to use application handlers:

```
        #get the render result
        render = bpy.data.images["Render Result"]
        
        #set the value of a compositor node to 0
        bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].node_tree.nodes["color vs. depth"].inputs[0].default_value = 0
        #change the colorspace to filmic
        bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Filmic'
        
        #save the image
        render.save_render(filepath = tool.my_path + tool.my_string + " COLOR.png")
```

Comment: it might be much easier to create a file output node in the compositor instead, this will anyways save the frame when you trigger a render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the compositor is processing with [bpy.app.is_job_running](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.is_job_running).

You do have to delay your script a little bit because the compositor process doesn't start until your script finishes. You can use [bpy.app.timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html).

```
import bpy

render = bpy.data.images["Render Result"]

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].node_tree.nodes["color vs. depth"].inputs[0].default_value = 0
bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Filmic'

def wait_for_compositing_and_save():
    if bpy.app.is_job_running("COMPOSITE"):
        return 0.01  # Try again in 0.01 seconds
    render.save_render(filepath = tool.my_path + tool.my_string + " COLOR.png")

bpy.app.timers.register(wait_for_compositing_and_save, first_interval=0.01)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!